# add a Maven dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies

I'm trying to develop a maven workflow guide for myself and I have gone so far to Install Maven, setup a Maven project, compile, package and run the jar file. Now I wish to add a dependency to the project.

After adding the dependency to the pom.xml I compile , package and run the jar, I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/DateTime
```

I still don' t understand this part of the process. I also tried mvn install and also don' t get where the the dependency files go? Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Source: [my test project (so far)](https://github.com/LucasHartman/myMavenTestProject/tree/main/myJava)

Comment: They are only used for compilation, they are not available at runtime. Unless you build an executable JAR with e.g. the Maven assembly plugin.

Comment: I will look further into Maven assembly plugin, Thx!